# how to detect the wget's download speed is zero from shell

Tags: linux, bash, wget

everyone.I tried to use this command: `wget -c -i file`. And often,some package may have zero download speed for a long time. So i want to skip these packages and go on wget next.
Now,the problem is how can i detect whether the download speed is zero for a specified time ,like 5 mins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from wget manual

```
   --read-timeout=seconds
       Set the read (and write) timeout to seconds seconds.  The "time" of
       this timeout refers to idle time: if, at any point in the download,
       no data is received for more than the specified number of seconds,
       reading fails and the download is restarted.  This option does not
       directly affect the duration of the entire download.

       Of course, the remote server may choose to terminate the connection
       sooner than this option requires.  The default read timeout is 900
       seconds.
```